# Select statement strange behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table :

```
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CAMXTimeStamp | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CAMXMessage   | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am trying to select the record with the lowest id :

```
select id from camxmessages having min(id);
```

And then the table looses all the records , and I not getting any result , any idea what i do wrong ?

Comment: AFAIK `having` can not be used without aggregate functions. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Harry Joy I was also surprised that it worked. `HAVING` should always be paired with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: looks awfully mysql specific. Do you really lose records from the table?

Comment: `min(id)` is a code smell (identifier does not normally imply ordering).

Comment: @Paul: @Szocske: HAVING without GROUP BY is allowed. Example that works in both MySQL and SQL-Server would be `SELECT MIN(id) FROM test HAVING MIN(id) > 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(ID)
FROM CAMXMESSAGES
```

Comment: That's the best way to do it. +1.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM camxmessages 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think `SELECT MIN(id) ...` is faster. I voted for @Giann's answer.

Comment: It is as long you don't want the rest of the row data

Comment: @ahmet: Both will perform quite fast. This will show the record with minimum id. Giann's will show only the minimum id. The OP states that he is trying *"to select the **record** with the lowest id"*

Comment: Hey, I was typing the same thing! :-) You get an upvote instead then.